# UITextField in custom UITableViewCell unexpectedly found nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, uitextfield

I have a `TableView` with custom cells that have a `TextField` inside, unfortunately I get a **Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** when I use them (press return or touch the screen outside the textField to get out of the placeholder).

**Here is my code :**

```
class WalletTableViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var cryptosArray: [Cryptos] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self

        loadCryptoArray()
    }

    func loadCryptoArray() {

        if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "cryptosArray") != nil {
            if let decoded = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "cryptosArray") as? Data? {
               let decodedCryptoArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded!) as! [Cryptos]
               cryptosArray = decodedCryptoArray
        }
    } 
}

}
```

**The `TableView` extension :**

```
extension WalletTableViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cryptosArray.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let crypto = cryptosArray[indexPath.row]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! WalletTableViewCell
        cell.setCrypto(crypto: crypto)
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.amountTextField.delegate = self

        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 85
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            cryptosArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

            let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
            let encodedData : Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: cryptosArray)
            userDefaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "cryptosArray")
            userDefaults.synchronize()
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the delegate function for the `TextField`:**

```
extension WalletTableViewController: CryptoCellDelegate {
    func cellAmountEntered(_ sender: Any) {
        if WalletTableViewCell().amountTextField.text == "" {
            return
        }
        let str = WalletTableViewCell().amountTextField.text

        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
        let dNumber = formatter.number(from: str!)
        let nDouble = dNumber!
        let eNumber = Double(truncating: nDouble)

        WalletTableViewCell().amountLabel.text = String(format:"%.8f", eNumber)

      UserDefaults.standard.set(WalletTableViewCell().amountLabel.text, forKey: "bitcoinAmount")
        WalletTableViewCell().amountTextField.text = ""

    }
}
```

**The custom cell file :**

```
protocol CryptoCellDelegate {
    func cellAmountEntered(_ sender: Any)
}

class WalletTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cryptoNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var amountLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var amountTextField: UITextField!

    var cryptoItem: Crypto!
    var delegate: CryptoCellDelegate?

    func setCrypto(crypto: Cryptos) {

        cryptoNameLabel.text = crypto.name
    }

    @IBAction func amountTextFieldEntered(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.cellAmountEntered((Any).self)
    }

}
```

The `TableView` has as many cells as the user wants, so this is depending on the `array` of objects that create the cells.

I guess I have a `delegate` problem somewhere? I am quite new to `UITableView` so this has been quite a challenge, forgive any stupid blunder :)

PS: I've tried to keep the code short by removing `keyboard` functions and unrelated stuff, please tell me if you need something else.

Comment: update the code in `extension WalletTableViewController: CryptoCellDelegate` because it is obviously uncompilable right now

Comment: bad paste skill, sorry about that

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: maybe your textfield's text is not integer value test this `let dNumber = Int(str) ? Int(str) : 0` instead of this `let dNumber = formatter.number(from: str!)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everywhere where you use `WalletTableViewCell()` you are creating a new instance of the `WalletTableViewCell`. The crash happens because you are creating it programmatically, while `WalletTableViewCell` was designed using storyboards, and since you did not instantiated it using storyboards, `@IBOutlet`s have not been set, therefore are `nil`.

**Update**

Try to fix it using this. Update `CryptoCellDelegate` to this:

```
protocol CryptoCellDelegate {
    func cellAmountEntered(_ walletTableViewCell: WalletTableViewCell)
}
```

Then in `WalletTableViewCell` update `amountTextFieldEntered` to:

```
@IBAction func amountTextFieldEntered(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.cellAmountEntered(self)
}
```

And finally update delegate implementation:

```
extension WalletTableViewController: CryptoCellDelegate {
    func cellAmountEntered(_ walletTableViewCell: WalletTableViewCell) {
        // now you can use walletTableViewCell to access the cell that called the delegate method
        if walletTableViewCell.amountTextField.text == "" {
            return
        }
        let str = walletTableViewCell.amountTextField.text

        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
        let dNumber = formatter.number(from: str!)
        let nDouble = dNumber!
        let eNumber = Double(truncating: nDouble)

        walletTableViewCell.amountLabel.text = String(format:"%.8f", eNumber)

        UserDefaults.standard.set(walletTableViewCell.amountLabel.text, forKey: "bitcoinAmount")
        walletTableViewCell.amountTextField.text = ""

    }
}
```

Comment: Milan hello again :) I thought  I was referencing `WalletTableViewCell `, I really need to study that again. I also thought delegating the function was enough to use `WalletTableViewCell` outlets and actions, does it mean I have to declare everything again in `WalletTableViewController` ?

Comment: @Martin33000 glad to help

Comment: As a suggestion @Martin33000, avoid doing `ClassName()`, and do instead `ClassName.init()`. Should be the same, and teach/remind you then that you a creating a whole new object each time until you assimilated it. Also, since that the cell is linked with a XIB (or Storyboard), then the IBOutlets are connected there, but nothing block you to do a init without that "UI link". And since you did `init()`, it didn't create an object linked with the XIB, so the Outlets were nil.