# Dynamically using specific variables with custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

**This question will be a follow-up of this [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49047174/uitextfield-in-custom-uitableviewcell-unexpectedly-found-nil/49047238#49047238).**

I'm at the point where the user can create `UITableViewCells` and enter an amount to a `TextField`. It is then printed to a label and *should* update a variable that will be used with another variable for a calculation (basically amount * currentPrice, this is a wallet).

I re-read Apple's doc about `TableViews` and re-opened the exercises I did when I followed the Swift course but I'm struggling to understand the principle here, so once again, I think I really need someone to explain differently than what I could read so my brain can understand.

How will the cell know what variable to use here:

**Entering the amount:**

```
func cellAmountEntered(_ walletTableViewCell: WalletTableViewCell) {

    if walletTableViewCell.amountTextField.text == "" {
        return
    }
    let str = walletTableViewCell.amountTextField.text

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
    let dNumber = formatter.number(from: str!)
    let nDouble = dNumber!
    let eNumber = Double(truncating: nDouble)

    walletTableViewCell.amountLabel.text = String(format:"%.8f", eNumber)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(walletTableViewCell.amountLabel.text, forKey: "cellAmount")
    walletTableViewCell.amountTextField.text = ""

}
```

**Calculations and display:**

```
func updateCellValueLabel(cryptoPrice: String) {

    if walletTableViewCell.amountLabel.text == "" {
        walletTableViewCell.amountLabel.text = "0.00000000"
    }

    let formatter1 = NumberFormatter()
    formatter1.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
    let str = walletTableViewCell.amountLabel.text
    let dNumber = formatter1.number(from: str!)
    let nDouble = dNumber!
    let eNumber = Double(truncating: nDouble)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(eNumber, forKey: "currentAmount")

    guard let cryptoDoublePrice = CryptoInfo.cryptoPriceDic[cryptoPrice] else { return }

    WalletViewController.bitcoinAmountValue = cryptoDoublePrice * eNumber

    if WalletViewController.currencyCode != "" {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "\(WalletViewController.currencyCode)")
        walletTableViewCell.cryptoValueLabel.text = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: WalletViewController.amountValue))
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(WalletViewController.walletDoubleValue, forKey: "walletValue")
}
```

What I can't process here is how can I **save** the amount entered to the corresponding crypto UserDefaults file, then **load** this amount to be **used** with the **corresponding variable** that has the current price for calculations.

I don't know how to use the correct data for the correct cell.

Should I make this a single function? Should I pass parameters to the function (how do I pass the correct parameters to the corresponding cell with delegate?)? Do I need an array of parameters that will be used at indexPath to the correct cell (but how do I know the order if the user creates cells at will?)?

I'm kind of lost here.

Comment: not sure if I understood correctly your question. But you can create an array and add values ther when user creates new cell. Meaning every new cell will have biggest index and you will be able to get values of that cell by that index

Comment: @Almazini you understood perfectly! What do you mean by `values`?