# Trigger `TableViewCell` function from `ViewWillAppear`

Tags: ios, swift, function, uitableview, core-data

I would like to **trigger `func updateCellValueLabel(...)` from `ViewWillAppear`** so my data is up to date when I open the view.

I might be overthinking the situation because of the `TableViewCell:` parameter which gives me access to `indexPath` but I can't figure out **how to call it.**

**View controller:**

```
class WalletTableViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    registerForKeyboardNotifications()
    self.hideKeyboard()

    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    if CDHandler.fetchObject() != nil {
        cryptos = CDHandler.fetchObject()!
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    erc20AddressTextField.delegate = self

    WalletTableViewCell.init().updateCellValue()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self


    if CDHandler.fetchObject() != nil {
        cryptos = CDHandler.fetchObject()!
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    WalletTableViewCell.init().updateCellValue()

}
```

}

**My table view extension:**

```
extension WalletTableViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CryptoCellDelegate {


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cryptos.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! WalletTableViewCell

    cell.cryptoNameLabel.text = cryptos[indexPath.row].name
    cell.cryptoCodeLabel.text = cryptos[indexPath.row].symbol
    cell.amountLabel.text = cryptos[indexPath.row].amount
    cell.amountTextField.placeholder = cryptos[indexPath.row].placeholder

    cell.delegate = self
    cell.amountTextField.delegate = self

    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    /*if editingStyle == .delete {
        cryptos.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        CDHandler.deleteObject(crypto: cryptos[indexPath.row])
    }*/
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let selectedManagedObject = cryptos[indexPath.row]
        CDHandler.deleteObject(entity:"CryptosMO", deleteObject: selectedManagedObject)
        cryptos.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}

// Value calculation & label update
//----------------------------------
func updateCellValueLabel(_ walletTableViewCell: WalletTableViewCell) {

    print("CALLED") // <--- This is never printed

    if walletTableViewCell.amountLabel.text == "" {
        walletTableViewCell.amountLabel.text = "0.00000000"
    }

    var newCryptos : [CryptosMO] = []
    var doubleAmount = 0.0
    var cryptoPrice = ""
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: walletTableViewCell)

    if CDHandler.fetchObject() != nil {
        newCryptos = CDHandler.fetchObject()!
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    cryptoPrice = cryptos[(indexPath?.row)!].code!
    guard let cryptoDoublePrice = CryptoInfo.cryptoPriceDic[cryptoPrice] else { return }

    let selectedAmount = newCryptos[(indexPath?.row)!]
    if let amount = selectedAmount.amount {
        doubleAmount = Double(amount)!
    }

    amountValue = cryptoDoublePrice * doubleAmount

    if WalletViewController.currencyCode != "" {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "\(WalletViewController.currencyCode)")
        walletTableViewCell.cryptoValueLabel.text = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: amountValue))
    }
}

}
```

**Table view cell:**

```
protocol CryptoCellDelegate {

func cellAmountEntered(_ walletTableViewCell: WalletTableViewCell)
func updateCellValueLabel(_ walletTableViewCell: WalletTableViewCell)
```

}

class WalletTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
func updateCellValue() {
    delegate?.updateCellValueLabel(self)
}

@IBAction func amountTextFieldEntered(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.cellAmountEntered(self)
    delegate?.updateCellValueLabel(self)
}
```

}

**How can I call `updateCellValueLabel(...)` whenever I want to refresh the data?**

Comment: can you explain your current scene in details ? what you are trying to archive or what is your desire output.?

Comment: viewDidLoad trigger before viewWillAppear. So better to update data in viewDidLoad()

Comment: @ravi.p This a wallet. Can you spot `updateCellValueLabel` in the code? The function takes the amount the user has stored in core data and update the wallet value with the `amount * coin value`. I want the wallet value to stay updated to the newest value (fetched elsewhere).

Comment: @JD. It's not called from `viewDidLoad()` either unfortunately :/

Comment: When I see this `WalletTableViewCell().updateCellValue()`, I remember saying this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49047174/uitextfield-in-custom-uitableviewcell-unexpectedly-found-nil#comment85099644_49047238)

Comment: @Larme you're right! I edited my code in question and the project, bad habits are hard to lose.

Comment: No, you missed one of the important part. `WalletTableViewCell.init()` That's creating a WHOLE NEW WalletTableViewCell object. So I don't think it will have the value you think of.

Comment: You're right, I need to find a way to call the original function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The func updateCellValueLabel(_ walletTableViewCell: WalletTableViewCell) takes as a parameter a WalletTableViewCell so you can't call it without passing as a parameter a cell.. so if you want to call it on viewDidAppear you will have to loop the tableview and call it for each cell, so in view viewDidAppear you should write something like..

```
for i in 0...self.tableview.numberOfSections - 1{
   self.updateCellValueLabel(_ walletTableViewCell: self.tableview.cellForRow(at: i))
}
```

and after that if you want to call it more times you can add it into a function and call the function

Comment: This looks great, but I'm getting `Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'IndexPath'` at `(at: i)`

Comment: try
`for cell in tableView.visibleCells() as! [WalletTableViewCell] {

            self.updateCellValueLabel(_ walletTableViewCell: cell)

        }`

Comment: Now I get `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` at `cryptoPrice = cryptos[(indexPath?.row)!].code!` inside ` updateCellValueLabel()` . There is something wrong with `indexPath` again haha

Comment: ok I think that the error is because the view didn't appeared yet and that that code would work on view did appear but try this code on view will appear
`for section in 0...self.tableView.numberOfSections-1{
            for row in 0...self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section) - 1{
                var indexP:IndexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
                self.updateCellValueLabel(_ walletTableViewCell: self.tableview.cellForRow(at: indexP))
            }
        }`

Comment: What kind of protection can I add to avoid a `Thread 1: Fatal error` if there are no rows?

Comment: you can add just an if but I'm telling you again it might not need the -1 so.. if it needs the -1 you add the row
`if(self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section) >= 1){
}`
but if it doesn't need the -1 it will not need anything